# How to keep files on the host trash which deleted from Docker container

Tags: docker

1. The host has the recycle bin enabled, and the deleted files will remain in the trash instead of being deleted directly
2. After mapping a directory to the docker container, deleting the file in the container will delete it directly instead of appearing on the host

How to make sure that the files deleted in the container appear in the recycle bin of the host?

Comment: If your application calls unlink(2) or a similar call to delete the file, it will get deleted in the container filesystem.  This doesn't have any notion of "recycle bin" or "trash can" even if various desktop environments do; the file is just gone.